# Copiar string para struct

Tags: c, c++, string, struct

Ao tentar copiar a String `nome` para dentro da String na Struct `novo->nome` o programa para de funcionar, caso eu comente a função `strcpy(novo->nome,nome);` o código é executado normalmente.

```
//Função de inserção:
lista *insere_lista(lista *l,char *nome,int idade){
    lista *novo = (lista *)malloc(sizeof(lista));

    strcpy(novo->nome,nome);
    novo->idade = idade;
    novo->proximo = l;
    return novo;
}

//Main:
int main(){
    int opc,idade;
    char *nome;

    lista *l;
    l = cria_lista();

    do{
        printf("\n1 - Inserir\n");
        printf("2 - Retirar\n");
        printf("3 - Mostrar\n");
        printf("4 - Busca\n");
        printf("0 - Sair\n");
        scanf("%d",&opc);

        if(opc == 1){
            printf("Digite o nome:");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s",&nome);
            printf("Digite a idade:");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d",&idade);

            l = insere_lista(l,nome,idade);
        }

        if(opc == 3){
            mostra_lista(l);
        }

    }while(opc!=0);
}

//Struct:
typedef struct lista{
    char *nome;
    int idade;
    struct lista *proximo;
}lista;
```

[image: Imagem do Erro]

Comment: Qual erro você está recebendo? Tente deixar a pergunta mais clara (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228373/copiar-string-para-struct).

Comment: `nome` já é um ponteiro, logo para fazer o `scanf` que estava a tentar fazer teria que ser `scanf("%s",nome);` sem o `&`. Não convem esquecer que o `scanf` recebe o endereço de memoria onde vai colocar os dados lidos

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema trocando `scanf("%s",&nome);` por `gets(nome);`